# Advanced Custom Fields - Adding Linkedin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-fields

I am having trouble creating a clickable Linkedin link in WordPress via [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) Plugin. It was simple when I wanted to add phone number and email. But I can not figure out how to make just a Linkedin icon appear for each user as a clickable link.

**Code:**
function member_contact() {

```
$vcard = get_field('vcard');
$bio   = get_field('bio_pdf');
$linkedin = get_field('linkedin');
$phone = get_field('phone');
$fax   = get_field('fax');
$email = get_field('email');

$post_info = '';

if (isset($vcard['url'])) {
    $img = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/images/mail-icon.png";
    $post_info .= '<a class="vcard" href="'.$vcard['url'].'"><img src="'.$img.'" /> Download Contact</a>';
}

if (isset($bio['url']) && isset($vcard['url'])) {
    $post_info .= ' | ';
}

if (isset($bio['url'])) {
    $post_info .= '<a class="bio-pdf" href="'.$bio['url'].'">Download Bio</a>';
}

if (isset($linkedin['url']) && isset($vcard['url']) || isset($bio['url'])) {
    $post_info .= ' | ';
}

if (isset($linkedin['url'])) {
    $post_info .= '<a href="'.$linkedin['url'].'"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" style="color:blue"></i> Linkedin</a>';
}


$post_info .= '<ul class="member-contact">';
$post_info .= "<li>$email</li>";
$post_info .= "<li>p: $phone</li>";
$post_info .= "<li>f: $fax</li>";
$post_info .= "</ul>";
var_dump($linkedin);
```

**Code from a user's repo (Kevinlearynet)**,which I am not sure how to integrate

```
                <?php if ( $linkedin = get_field('team_linkedin') ): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $linkedin; ?>"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
```

**Dump for $linkedin**

```
string(21) "https://www.yahoo.com"
```

**Pictures:**
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? I see you're assigning the LinkedIn field to a variable ($linkedin) but then you've never tried to do anything with it.

Comment: That is the problem I am not sure what do besides a basic post.  $post_info .= "<li>$linkedin</li>";   

Which will only post the field as text and not a clickable link nor icon ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your code like this to integrate the linkedin link.

```
function member_contact() {

        $vcard = get_field('vcard');
        $bio   = get_field('bio_pdf');
        $phone = get_field('phone');
        $fax   = get_field('fax');
        $linkedin = get_field('linkedin');
        $email = get_field('email');

        $post_info = '';

        if (isset($vcard['url'])) {
            $img = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/images/mail-icon.png";
            $post_info .= '<a class="vcard" href="'.$vcard['url'].'"><img src="'.$img.'" /> Download Contact</a>';
        }

        if (isset($bio['url']) && isset($vcard['url'])) {
            $post_info .= ' | ';
        }

        if (isset($bio['url'])) {
            $post_info .= '<a class="bio-pdf" href="'.$bio['url'].'">Download Bio</a>';
        }

        $post_info .= '<ul class="member-contact">';
        $post_info .= "<li>$email</li>";
        $post_info .= "<li>p: $phone</li>";
        $post_info .= '<a href="$linkedin"><i class="icon-linkedin"></i></a>';
        $post_info .= "<li>f: $fax</li>";
        $post_info .= "</ul>";

        genesis_markup( array(
            'html5' => sprintf( '<div class="entry-meta">%s</div>', $post_info ),
            'xhtml' => sprintf( '<div class="post-info">%s</div>', $post_info ),
        ) );

    }
```

Comment: Sadly with this code the site generates the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home1/king/public_html/wp-content/themes/king/single-member.php on line 74

Comment: That worked I think but it is not appearing on the site. I believe it is because Font Awesome is not on my site. What would recommend to add font awesome to this file? Would this odd plugin work, https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-font-awesome/installation/

Comment: no, you should include the font awesome css file and it will work http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/

Comment: Will the CDN at the top of the .php file will do the trick? Sorry 1 second let me test it out before wasting your time :D

Comment: It is a CSS file and you need to put in your page <head></head>, you should do it using the wp_enqueue_script funtion in your functions.php file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81893/discussion-between-theace-and-genethic).

Answer (score 1):

You are already assigning the LinkedIn field to a variable, so you just need to construct the link now:

function member_contact() {

```
$vcard = get_field('vcard');
$bio   = get_field('bio_pdf');
$phone = get_field('phone');
$fax   = get_field('fax');
$linkedin = get_field('linkedin');
$email = get_field('email');

$post_info = '';

if (isset($vcard['url'])) {
    $img = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/images/mail-icon.png";
    $post_info .= '<a class="vcard" href="'.$vcard['url'].'"><img src="'.$img.'" /> Download Contact</a>';
}

if (isset($bio['url']) && isset($vcard['url'])) {
    $post_info .= ' | ';
}

if (isset($bio['url'])) {
    $post_info .= '<a class="bio-pdf" href="'.$bio['url'].'">Download Bio</a>';
}

$post_info .= '<ul class="member-contact">';
$post_info .= "<li>$email</li>";
$post_info .= "<li>p: $phone</li>";
$post_info .= "<li>f: $fax</li>";
//NEW LINE ADDED BELOW
$post_info .= "<li><a href="'.$linkedin.'" class="linkedInButton"></a></li>";
//NEW LINE ADDED ABOVE
$post_info .= "</ul>";

genesis_markup( array(
    'html5' => sprintf( '<div class="entry-meta">%s</div>', $post_info ),
    'xhtml' => sprintf( '<div class="post-info">%s</div>', $post_info ),
) );
```

}

This will output your LinkedIn link immediately after the Fax Number in this function.

Then you would just need to style your  tag with the class "linkedInButton" to have a LinkedIn icon as a background image, set the height and width of the icon, change its display to block or inline-block (as needed), and you'll be all set.

As an FYI, Advanced Custom Fields has a URL field which I'd recommend using instead of a text field. Doing this incorporates some validation to ensure that a valid URL is used.

Comment: I will def.ly change the field type to URL but sadly with this code the site will generate the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''.$linkedin.'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /home1/king/public_html/wp-content/themes/king/single-member.php on line 74